# "An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant" error when I try to add a yesterday date to GET parameters (NASA APOD API)

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, get-request

I have a problem creating a correct @GET request with NASA APOD API. According to the documentation I can add a specific date to the request using a "date" parameter, for example, date=2020-03-21: https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date=2020-03-21&api_key=DEMO_KEY In this case everything works just fine. But when I try to modify a request to load a yesterday photo I have an error. I have to pass somehow a yesterday date to the "date" parameter but I can't understand how to do it: https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date=*YESTERDAY_DATE_HERE*&api_key=DEMO_KEY

I tried to create a LocalDate variable, but I received a Build Error: **An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant**

I would appreciate any help!

My code:

```
interface NasaApiService {

    val yesterdayDate: LocalDate
        get() = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1)

    @GET("planetary/apod?date=$yesterdayDate&api_key=" + BuildConfig.NASA_API_KEY)
    fun getYesterdayPhoto(): Call<NasaPhoto>

    companion object {

        private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.nasa.gov/"

        fun returnToVmFunction(): NasaApiService {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(NasaApiService::class.java)

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed only pass compile-time constants as arguments to annotations, and parameterized strings are not compile-time constants. Use Retrofit's `@Query` parameters instead:

```
@GET("planetary/apod")
fun getYesterdayPhoto(
  @Query("date") date: String,
  @Query("api_key") apiKey: String,
): Call<NasaPhoto>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Value("${stripe.key}")
private val stripeKey: String? = null

usually using \ in front of $ solves the issue